# Not getting albums of some users in facebook sdk graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am querying in graph api like this `/userid/albums`

I am getting response of most users successful but I am though not getting response of some users. It give me blank response-

```
{
   "data": [ ]
}
```

Comment: Did those users give you the `user_photos` permission?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the user for `user_photos`/`friends_photos` in order to get the albums of the concerned user or his friends.

Comment: i have try all following permission though i am not getting the response of some users. 

friends_about_me,
friends_activities, 
friends_events,  
friends_groups, 
friends_likes, 
friends_notes, 
friends_photos, 
friends_status,

Comment: Pls elaborate what response are you not getting , and for how many users?

Comment: i m just query like this /userid/albums in graph api explorer i m getting this response for some userid not all.                                                 {
   "data": [ ]
}

Comment: you can try yourself this query, you can not get some of user albums.

Comment: Only some the albums right? This is normal, some users set rivacy to some of their albums.